# make: *** No rule to make target 'population'. Stop. cs50

Tags: cs50, edx

make: *** No rule to make target 'population'.  Stop.
[No rule to make target 'population'.  Stop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA5J7.png)

I'm trying to compile cs50's population problem set-1 population. it doesn't works , showing this error message on terminal "make: *** No rule to make target 'population'.  Stop.",
later on I tried other file to compile it says also same ..

thanks in advance

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The picture shows some code in the programming language C, plus an error message from `make`. Most likely the problem comes from the `Makefile` you used to compile your code, not from the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terminal shows that `make` is being run from the home directory (`~/).

The file tree shows that `population.c` lives in `~/pset1/hello` directory.

`cd` to the directory where the source code exists and then execute `make`.

Answer (score 0):

you are in wrong directory, use `ls` in terminal to show you the directory you're in include which files. you are in some directory the file you want to compile, didn't create in this directory you are, use `pwd` in terminal to show your the address(path).